# How to properly parse file name from B-form-file dynamic component in BootstrapVue

Tags: frontend, bootstrap-vue

I am using the BootstrapVue `<component>` tag to display components given their name and other properties. My generic component looks like this:

`<component :is="componentName" v-model="key" v-bind="properties"></component>`

I have a .js file where I define the component together with its properties like this:

`{key: '', component: '', properties: { class: '', placeholder: ''} }`

In case I want to set BFormFile component my meta data looks like this:

`{key: 'file', component: 'BFormFile', properties: { placeholder: 'Upload image here '}`

When I upload a file image I want to get the file name and save it in a json object. But I receive an error of the following type:

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token (MismatchedInputException)

Could someone give me some opinion about this problem ?

Comment: Could you provide a code example of how you are calling JSON.stringify/parse?

Comment: Also note that `File` object instances cannot be directly serialized as JSON